# Error list while installing laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, package

Hello i am tying to install laravel package called [Voyager Frontend](https://github.com/pvtl/voyager-frontend) once i used the command `composer require pvtl/voyager-frontend` i received the following error list

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: The package doesn't seem to support Laravel 5.6.   Specifically one of it's dependencies.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to swap to another version like 5.5 on the current project and is it flexible to swap between versions because i am afraid to cause problems from this step

Comment: No, it's not usually simple to swap from one version to the next, especially downgrading.  You'd have to look at the Laravel 5.5 to 5.6 upgrade guide and reverse the steps.

Comment: Please don't share error messages as an image

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest starting from scratch using a supported version of Laravel

```
$ composer create-project laravel/laravel projectName "5.5.*"
$ cd projectName
$ composer require tcg/voyager
$ composer require pvtl/voyager-frontend
```